# Provide example for a certain reaarangement invariant Banach space of Lebesgue-measurable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I look for an example of a rearrangement invariant Banach space X of Lebesgue-measurable functions on $(0,1)$, preferably, which meets the following criterion:
There exists a function $g>0$ in $X$ and a function $h$ with $|h| \leq g$ but $h$ is not in $X$.

Comment: Why don't you take a non-measurable subset $M$ of $(0,1)$, $h(t)=1$ for $t\in M$, $h(t)=-1$ otherwise and $g=1_{(0,1)}\in L_1(0,1)$?

Comment: @TomekKania: I would presume that the implicit assumption is that $h$ is measurable.

Comment: Sorry, I meant h to be (Lebesque)-measurable as well (otherwise, naturally, the example stated is valid). So the precise statement is: I look for an example of a rearrangement invariant Banach space X of Lebesque-measurable functions on (0,1) which meets the following criterion: There exists a (Lebesque-) measurable function g>0 in X and a function h with |h|≤g but h is not in X.

Comment: Sorry, I meant h to be (Lebesque)-measurable as well (otherwise, naturally, the example stated is valid). So the precise statement is: I look for an example of a rearrangement invariant Banach space X of Lebesque-measurable functions on (0,1) which meets the following criterion: There exists a (Lebesque-) measurable function g>0 in X and a Lebesque-measurable function h with |h|≤g but h is not in X.

Comment: Yes, the function h needs to be Lebesgue-measurable (thanks for the comment, PhoemueX), otherwise the (counter)example of Tomasz would work.